# Copy unselectable text - Fooview like app for Windows

Tags: windows, android, clipboard

Is there any app for Windows to copy unselectable text?

Something like the Android app [FooView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fooview.android.fooview) does?

**Sample unselectable text** from a Windows settings screen:

[image: Sample unselectable text from a Windows settings screen]

Comment: Does Fooview do OCR? Otherwise any screen capture software will do...

Comment: Fooview will do OCR for pictures only;

Answer (score 1):

[Textify](https://rammichael.com/textify#more-1605) - A tool for Windows to copy text from dialogs and controls which don’t allow it otherwise

[Capture2Text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) - Capture2Text enables users to quickly OCR a portion of the screen using a keyboard shortcut. The resulting text will be saved to the clipboard by default.

Answer (score 1):

NirSoft's [SysExporter](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) is an excellent tool for capturing text that is displayed in Windows but cannot be selected.  I have used it many times.

It is closed-source portable freeware, and voluntary donations can be made [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/donate.html).

Compatibility details from the official website:

> SysExporter Works perfectly on Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.
>   On Windows 9x and Windows ME, SysExporter can only export data from combo boxes and list boxes controls, but not from list-view and tree-view controls.